# How can I redirect using vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have tried to access to others pages via url, but those pages never loads

- http://localhost:8080/index
- http://localhost:8080/about

This is my main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import Index from './views/Index';
const About = { template: '<p>about page</p>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/index', name: 'index', component: Index },
  { path: '/about', name: 'about', component: About }
]

var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: routes,
  mode: 'history'
})

new Vue({
  router: router,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Does anyone can help me with vue-router? i am new in this framework

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you access them like this:

http://localhost:8080/#/about

If yes, your `vue-router` is working in the default *hash-mode*. To get rid of the hash and get "normal" URLs you'll need to set it to [history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode).

**Edit:**

As I see you're already using history mode. Do you use Vue CLI for local development? This should normally [work out of the box](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#routing-with-history-pushstate). If not, you need to setup some redirect rules on other web servers. Please see the examples here: [Example Server Configurations](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

**Edit 2:**
Can you show your `App` component?
I tried to reproduce your problem in a sandbox, but it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-voice-zyg07

The `App` component here looks like this, including the router-view:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view id="page"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {}
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please see my edit. Seems like you're already using _history mode_. Maybe you are missing the redirect rules for your local web server if you're not using Vue CLI?